# Получение отзывов с яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, php, html, яндекс-карты

У самого получилось парсить страницу отзывов, но из-за скрипта яндекса выдаёт максимум 51 отзыв, вот мне интересно, есть ли сам скрипт от яндекса который подгружает эти отзывы на прямую? (сам не нашёл)

Comment: я смог получить вот это с яндекс карт https://yandex.ru/maps/api/business/fetchReviews?ajax=1&businessId=1607357284&csrfToken=ef5800cf295c836c5121dd71add824690b17e499:1662372698&lang=ru&page=1&pageSize=50&ranking=by_time&reqId=1662372703298494-894204808-addrs-upper-yp-92&s=864386581&sessionId=1662372698323_561988

(и вот как можно получить вот эти данные)
&csrfToken=ef5800cf295c836c5121dd71add824690b17e499:166237269
&reqId=1662372703298494-894204808-addrs-upper-yp-92
&s=864386581
&sessionId=1662372698323_561988

Comment: Токен сам генерируется, если вы корректно работаете с JS. Любые недокументированные запросы напрямую к http-ручкам JS API Яндекс считает злостным нарушением их условий, и выдавать возможные методы (если есть) для обхода их базовых защит едва ли будут публично.

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время у Яндекса нет API отзывов (или скрипта), который позволил бы загружать отзывы на организации сторонним пользователям.

Все же методы, не описанные в какой-либо документации (тот же парсинг) нецелесообразны для применения любого более-менее коммерческого сценария, поскольку в любой момент Яндекс может изменить структуру или формат данных, либо вообще заблокировать доступ к сервису за нарушение [пользовательского соглашения](https://yandex.ru/legal/maps_termsofuse/?lang=ru), которое явным образом разрешает использование методов лишь "***предусмотренных функциональными возможностями сервиса***".